# Failed building wheel for scikit-image

Tags: python

ERROR: Failed building wheel for scikit-image
Failed to build scikit-image
ERROR: Could not build wheels for scikit-image, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to upgrade pip ( python -m pip install --upgrade pip )?

Try installing numpy first too.